# Jsfiddle is not working on file

Tags: javascript

I have Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7owj48qt/ but I can't get it working outside Jsfiddle. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<img id="preload1" style="transition: all 2400ms;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/wheel.png" data-rotate="600" height="40%" width="40%" />

<img id="preload1" style="transition: all 2400ms;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/wheel.png" data-rotate="1000" height="40%" width="40%" />
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var deg = $(this).data('rotate') || 0;
    var rotate = 'rotate(' + $(this).data('rotate') + 'deg)';
    $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': rotate,
            '-moz-transform': rotate,
            '-o-transform': rotate,
            '-ms-transform': rotate,
            'transform': rotate
    });
});
```

Comment: you included the `javascript` reference in the `html`?

Comment: There are two pretty likely but completely different causes for this, but no way to diagnose which without seeing more of the code or knowing what errors are reported on the JS console.

Comment: Have you included your code in a `$(document).ready(){` in your script?

Comment: Images are not moving. Probably script is not working. I just inserted it between <script></script>, but seems that something else is missing.

Comment: @jal_est — And what other scripts do you have? And where in the HTML did you put those scripts?

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" ></script>

<img id="preload1" style="transition: all 2400ms;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/wheel.png" data-rotate="600" height="40%" width="40%" />

<img id="preload1" style="transition: all 2400ms;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/wheel.png" data-rotate="1000" height="40%" width="40%" />



 <script>
$(window).on("load", function(){
$('img').each(function () {
    var deg = $(this).data('rotate') || 0;
    var rotate = 'rotate(' + $(this).data('rotate') + 'deg)';
    $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': rotate,
            '-moz-transform': rotate,
            '-o-transform': rotate,
            '-ms-transform': rotate,
            'transform': rotate
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function () {
        var deg = $(this).data('rotate') || 0;
        var rotate = 'rotate(' + $(this).data('rotate') + 'deg)';
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': rotate,
                '-moz-transform': rotate,
                '-o-transform': rotate,
                '-ms-transform': rotate,
                'transform': rotate
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function once the image is loaded. to do this use jquery onload.

```
$( "img" ).load(function() {
  var deg = $(this).data('rotate') || 0;
    var rotate = 'rotate(' + $(this).data('rotate') + 'deg)';
    $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': rotate,
            '-moz-transform': rotate,
            '-o-transform': rotate,
            '-ms-transform': rotate,
            'transform': rotate
    });
});
```

The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object

Answer (score 0):

Like always, after posting found mistake.
I had:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min"></script>
```

.js was missing. Thanks for quick answers.

This one works.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function () {
        var deg = $(this).data('rotate') || 0;
        var rotate = 'rotate(' + $(this).data('rotate') + 'deg)';
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': rotate,
                '-moz-transform': rotate,
                '-o-transform': rotate,
                '-ms-transform': rotate,
                'transform': rotate
        });
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="preload1" style="transition: all 2400ms;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/wheel.png" data-rotate="200" height="40%" width="40%" />
<img id="preload1" style="transition: all 2400ms;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/wheel.png" data-rotate="-200" height="40%" width="40%" />

</body>
</html>
```